# How do I get rid of a phantom Xcode error in empty file?

Tags: xcode

This seems to be nothing more than annoying, but very annoying it is. I made a typo and got an error, as expected. However after fixing it the error persisted.
Even after deleting the contents of the file, and replacing with line breaks, the error always appears on line 29, even after saving, restarting Xcode, restarting my computer and so on.

[phantom error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ltaoo.png)

EDIT: I copied the file contents to a new file and deleted the original one, but curios to know if I'm missing something?

Comment: Just remove that line

Comment: @KuvonchbekYakubov  Did you look at the screen shot? I removed everything in the file and replaced it with line breaks. Every time I reach line 29, no matter the contents - even a blank line - that error message shows

Comment: Did you clean project? That error was appearing when I use non Mac keyboard.

Comment: Clean project didn't help. I deleted the file and pasted the contents to a new file.

Comment: I have the same problem. To me, nothing helped. I tried:
1. Clean the project
2. OPTION + Clean the project
3. Deleting the code
4. Deleting the code and replacing the content of that line with something else
5. Product -> Clear all issues (worked instantly, but every next time i build, error appears normally as if nothing happened. There phantom errors are very , very persisting, even stronger than GIT it seems, or any kind of file saving system in existence :) :) very very annoying......

Comment: same bruh removed a file and all related code. Phantom errors where ever I previously referenced that file. Cleaned build, deleted derived data, etc. Errors persist, wtf!